# Automatically get first item from drop down list to the input

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, input

Is it possible to automatically get first item from drop down list to the input on page load? For example, the drop down list have 2 options: `happy`& `sad`. When the page loads, I want `happy` to be in the input on page load. So far, I got an empty input where the user need to select the option on the drop down list.

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#username_select").change(function() { 
            $("#username_custom").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

username_custom id:

```
<input id="username_custom" name="custom" value="
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['getusername'])) {

$getusername = $_POST['getusername']; 
echo "".$getusername."";

}
if(empty($_POST['username'])) {

    echo "".$row['username']."";

}
?>
">
```

username_select id:

```
<select id="username_select" name="getusername">
<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM account WHERE websiteusername='".$username."'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<option value='".$row['username']."'>".$row['username']."</option>";

}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the selected value of select in input

```
$("#YourInputId").val($("#username_custom").val());
```

To set the first option text of select

```
$("#YourInputId").val($("#username_custom option:eq(0)").text());
```

To change the textbox value on change of select

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#username_select").change(function() { 
        $("#username_custom").val($(this).val());
        $("#YourInputId").val($("#username_custom").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
echo "<option value='".$row['username']."'>".$row['username']."</option>";
```

you can add SELECTED to the option you want to get selected. You can use a  variable in the while loop to find out which item you are at and get that item selected;

For ex.

```
$ctr = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   echo "<option value='".$row['username']."'" . ( $ctr == 1 ? "selected" : "" ) . ">".$row['username']."</option>";
   $ctr++
}
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can also call change event of drop down.

```
$("#username_select").change();
```